# Jsoup parse throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: html, jsoup

I want to parse a html string. It throws the exception as follow.
The content length is greater than 65536, it that the problem? Thanks!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 66467
    at org.jsoup.parser.CharacterReader.nextIndexOf(CharacterReader.java:92)
    at org.jsoup.parser.CharacterReader.containsIgnoreCase(CharacterReader.java:277)
    at org.jsoup.parser.TokeniserState$11.read(TokeniserState.java:219)
    at org.jsoup.parser.Tokeniser.read(Tokeniser.java:42)
    at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.runParser(TreeBuilder.java:47)
    at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.parse(TreeBuilder.java:41)
    at org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilder.parse(HtmlTreeBuilder.java:37)
    at org.jsoup.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:90)
    at org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(Jsoup.java:58)
    at myproject.MyIndexer.getTitle(MyIndexer.java:137)
    at myproject.MyIndexer.indexDocs(MyIndexer.java:115)
    at myproject.MyIndexer.main(MyIndexer.java:80)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should'nt be the cause. `nextIndexOf()` uses only Integer:

```
int nextIndexOf(CharSequence seq) {
    // doesn't handle scanning for surrogates
    char startChar = seq.charAt(0);
    for (int offset = pos; offset < length; offset++) {
        // scan to first instance of startchar:
        if (startChar != input[offset])
            while(++offset < length && startChar != input[offset]);
        if (offset < length) {
            int i = offset + 1;
            int last = i + seq.length()-1;
            for (int j = 1; i < last && seq.charAt(j) == input[i]; i++, j++);     /* Line 92 */
            if (i == last) // found full sequence
                return offset - pos;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

*(I've makred line 92 where the exception is thrown)*

Now, `int` in Java has a range *–2.147.483.648* to *2.147.483.647*. 65536 is only relevant if you are using `unsigned short` (not available in java).

Please check ...

- if your input is valid html
- if this exception is thrown even with shorter length html
- if your code can influence the parsing
- if you have any non-unicode chars in your html - contrary to `int` - the `char` type is only 16 Bit (that means: upper bound is `65535`!)

You can also run your program in debug an check the variables after exeption is thrown. Especially the values of `seq.charAt(j)` and `input[i]` may be interesting.

Comment: You are right! It is not the cause of the html content length. I tried to remove some response header before I sent it the parse. It seems that I introduce some something the Jsoup can't parse. Do you happen to know how Jsoup remove the response header intuitively? I mean the header "HTTP/1.1 200" OK to "ContentLength:16254"

Comment: If you connect to a website better use `connect()`, not `parse()` method. you can remove any kind of element by selecting it and calling `remove()` then.